# Manually trigger 'change' event on input with payload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dom-events

I am implementing drag and drop file uploading for an input element but I have some difficulty with handling the drop event. I have the following html:

```
<label for="input" id="label" ondrop="handleDrop(event)">
    <input id="input" type="file" name="file"/>
    <span>Choose a file or drag it here.</span>
</label>
```

and the following js:

```
let label = document.getElementById('label');
let input = document.getElementById('input');
label.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
input.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let file = e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(file);
    //and now?
}

function handleChange(e) {
    //default not overwritten
    let fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    if (fileName) {
        input.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = fileName;
    }
}
```

when I click the input and browse for a file a 'change' event is fired, the text is set to the uploaded file and the 'file' attribute is set to this file. I want to have the same happen when a file is dropped on the label but I have no idea how to do this. I can use `input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))` but that will not deliver the file that is dropped into the file attribute of the input.

Maybe i'm thinking this problem through wrongly and there is a better alternative to do this, but the ultimate goal is of course to send the file to my server when I click the submit button. (I use Spring MVC by the way where the file is caught using `@RequestParam("file") Multipartfile file`.)

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what i'm trying to do is impossible since the file attribute of an `input type="file"` is read-only for security reasons. Proper way to do this would probably be to send the file to the MVC directly.